# ASP.NET unable to locate a class within the same namespace/scope

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing an ASP.NET web application.
I defined a service `WSDataService`, and another couple of classes `CUtilities` and `CDatabase`.
`WSDataService.asmx` (and related `WSDataService.asmx.cs`) is placed in the root folder, `CUtilities.cs` and `CDatabase.cs` are placed in `App_Code` folder.

**CUtilities.cs**:

```
namespace app
{
    public class CUtilities
    {   
        public static string CONNECTION_STRING = "";
    }
}
```

**WSDataService.asmx.cs**:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace app
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://www.app.it/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WSDataService : WebService
    {
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public string GetNumeroDocumento(string type, string series, string data)
        {
            CDataBase db = new CDataBase(CUtilities.CONNECTION_STRING);

            // DO SOMETHING with db
        }
    }
}
```

**WSDataService.asmx**:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="WSDataService.asmx.cs" Class="app.WSDataService" %>
```

When I try to compile I got this:

```
Gravità Codice  Descrizione Progetto    File    Riga    Stato eliminazione
Errore  CS0103  Il nome 'CUtilities' non esiste nel contesto corrente   site    C:\Users\user.me\Projects\APP\site\ThumbnailHandler.ashx.cs 23  Attivo
```

It seems that `CUtilities` is not in the scope (same error also for `CDatabase`).

`CUtilities` and `CDatabase` are compiling correctly AFAIK.

I cannot understand how to fix this.

Comment: Move CUtilities out of App_Cata, it's a special folder and shouldn't be used like this

Comment: Can I use another folder to separate the classes from pages in the root folder?

Comment: Yeah, you can use any folders you like, but App_Code and App_Data are special folders.

Comment: I moved `CUtilities.cs` and `CDatabase.cs` in `Classes` folder ... same result.

Comment: What are you using to compile your project?

Comment: I just created the site project from within VisualStudio I did not changed compilation settings for the project.

Comment: Just a recommendation based on my experience: don't implement asmx services. Write a REST-Service based on .NET Core Web API and one day you will benefit from it.

Comment: @SebastianS.  thnx for your suggestion but unluckly I need to *clone* the structure of an existing site changing it as little as possible. Since the this `.asmx` works as a gateway for a large number of `Ajax` scripts writing it as a `REST` service imply a full rewrite of (hundreds) of scripts ... to much work for this job.

Comment: @phuzi getting back on the issue. Should this depends on the way I created the project? When I created the project I selected `Applicazione Web ASP.NET (.NET framework)` this kind of solution create a `.csproj` file.
I think the original site was being created as `Sito Web Forms ASP.NET` (did not create a `.csproj`). `ASP.NET Web App (.NET Framework)` require some special feature on server side? I'm running `IIS 7.0` there.